# How do I create a 24 hour timer circuit capable of turning a servo on and off

Tags: relay, timer, servo

I need to design a timer circuit based on a 24 hour cycle that will trigger a 3V servo in one direction for a given duration then in the other direction once x amount of time has passed ( 5, 10, 15 min ). I would like to create the circuit simply and cheaply as possible. I aware the question id probably vague, but I'm really looking for a starting point.

Comment: Are you looking for a microcontroller-based solution, or is programming a microcontroller a problem for this application?

Comment: was actually leaning away from the microcontroller solution do to power consumption and cost, I'm a little unclear if this is something that can be achieved with a relatively simple timing circuit

Comment: In general, 24hr timing is best done in the digital domain -- but why is power consumption an issue for the microcontroller solution? Modern uCs can get submicroamp sleep currents for $1 in onesies...or is the issue the cost of programmers, etal?

Comment: perhaps it's not an issue then, I want it to be able to operate off of 2 or 3 double a batteries and I was making assumptions

Comment: seriously, even a power-hungry microprocessor will probably eat less power in 24h than your servo in a couple of turns, if you just enable sleep mode for as long as the µC has nothing to do.

Comment: There is a 555 **version** that could act as the low power main 24hr timer - the CSS555C http://www.customsiliconsolutions.com/downloads/Revised%20Standard%20products/CSS555C_Spec.pdf

Comment: - 1st start by defining all timer options and tolerances.,
- It is far simpler to do this in a uC, if you know someone who has done this before.

- Otherwise it takes a bunch of counters and gates, with the most popular being a 74HC4060 Ripple Counter with a cheap  $2, 2ppm TCXO. a 74HC4017 Decade counter and choose a frequency that is a binary multiple  of 5 minutes then another divider for 25 Hrs. = 288 or "1 0010 0000" with a 9 stage counter gated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really, go for microcontrollers.

Having a microprocessor with a stable external oscillator / quartz isn't expensive at all.

For example, take a sub-$1 [ST STM32F030K6](http://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers/stm32f030k6.html). If put into stop mode with an external oscillator for the integrated Real-time clock, it'll consume less than 10 µA, including leakage current in decoupling capacitors.

First, to put this into perspective: A typical AA battery has a self-discharge rate of 4% per year, at a capacity of 2.8 Ah (says German wikipedia). That means it has a continuous self-discharge current of ca. 12.8 µA!

In other words, if your AA battery was good for about 10 years lying around in a cupboard, it's now worth 5 years lying around in the cupboard, driving your microcontroller in stop mode. The fact that you'll turn your servo will cost many many times more energy than keeping the real-time clock running.

Regarding configuration:

yes, dedicating a few of the microcontroller's pins to a DIP switch will work to let the user select e.g. the time between turning back and forth; other options would include:

- attaching a (debounced) button to an wake-up capable pin
- a nice turn knob
- pin headers and jumpers
- software on a PC (you can buy similar microcontrollers that come with USB!)
- a potentiometer to let the user smoothly select a time (be sure to only apply power to the potentiometer very rarely – otherwise, it'll be a significant drain of power, unless you choose a very large resistance, but that might be hard to properly read out)
- …

Comment: that really puts it into perspective

Comment: How accurate is the timer in the processor?

Comment: as accurate as the 32768 Hz oscillator you attach. So, as good as your quartz watch, or better. Depends on how many cents you spend on an oscillator.

Comment: Did you see the "create the circuit simply" bit in the OPs question?  I'm always confused when people suggest commercial uControllers that have to be programmed in C using a very expensive and complex tool chain.  If the OP is asking such a fundamentally simple question (no disrespect to him), are interrupt tables, address register manipulation and linkers the appropriate way to go?

Comment: Paul, you might be overestimating the complexity of installing a MCU manufacturer's ide and modifying the blinking LED example...

Answer (score 1):

There are loads of different ways to create a timer circuit, although they all have drawbacks.

**RC Timer**

This can be done by just having an RC circuit where the time taken is

$$\tau = RC $$

The problem is that accuracy is a major issue with this circuit and the time you choose is fixed. It is a simple and cheap solution

**555 Based Timer**
This would work by creating a PWM frequency of your choice and using a counter IC to count the number of pulses.

A 555 timer circuit will be more accurate than a RC circuit but will still not be that accurate and will have a fixed time that it counts to. It is also quite cheap.

**Processor Based**

This option will give quite a lot of flexibility because you will be able to program the times so they can change dynamically. The timing on a processor (for example an ATTINY board) is not very precise unless you use an external crystal. Even then the accuracy will go out of sync with the real world. To solve this you can give the system an internet connection and sync the time with the BMT time.

A processor option can also be a cheap option, although once the system gets complex say with external crystal and wifi module it gets quite expensive and the software becomes more complicated.

**Suggestion**

Would definitely go for a cheap processor option, it is simple and cheap so long as you don't require super accurate timing. The rc filter and 555 timer options will be complex to get your whole system to work and the timing will be awful.

Comment: seems like microcontroller is the way to go perhaps an attiny, trying to figure out the simplest way to take user input of a variable time frame, perhaps a DIP switch ?